# Building a Rest server with delphi, wrapping all tables in a web module action component?

Tags: rest, delphi, delphi-2010

Hello I want to build a rest server with delphi and I found that really nice video from embarcadero on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_P6waeTlhVc And i would have asked the question directly on youtube but seeing there are 3 comments and not a single answer from them i don't want to waste my time waiting for their answer.

So basicly in this video the guy explains how to make a rest server and he builds all the client side and server side. In his example he creates a method on his server side to get employes (with all CRUD operations) and what bothers me is that he actually makes a wrapper for one table which is Employees and creates a web module action that get the type of request (get put post or delete) and calls the corresponding procedure for that.

So this looks kinda terrifying but what if i have 1000 tables? Do i have to make a web module action for each with all the CRUD operations for each of the tables? That seems extremly painful to me. Or is this the normal way to implement rest on server side?

Comment: Naturally, I find the built-in web components too awkward to work with, and I typically resort to rolling out my own REST server for this exact reason. RAD stands for Rapid Application Development, and Delphi tries to get you to use all the built-in pre-made stuff to get things up and running fast. But, they should not be necessarily relied on for massive projects like your own. Taking control over how your HTTP server works is by far worth the time and effort, so long as it's done properly.

Comment: It is not a nice approach, but using dmvcframework you can do it in a quite simple way (I'm the lead developer).
dmvcframework is the most popular Delphi framework on github.


https://github.com/danieleteti/delphimvcframework

Use the version 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I think in that case you should use a more generic aproach, and create CRUD operations in a generic, not specifically for a table. I mean something like update_table(dataset,table_name), insert_record(dataset,table_name) and so on. Each dataset represent a specific record from a specific table. With four methods you can get all you need. Maybe the problem is not suitable to implement the business logic at that level, so you need to put it by example at database. With Delphi Datasnap REST, you can pass datasets as parameters.